# Big Query - UID ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER() Issue

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have an issue by using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` with Big Query.

An issue is that when I create a view by using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` it works perfectly, **BUT** after half a day - day (My assumption, because of cache) number which generated by this command is changed.

Because I create another solid table and still refers to the view.  WHAT is the best way to create `ROW_NUMBER() OVER() - UID` AS solid unchanged numbers?

I have tried already  - `OW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DATE)` but it still changed.

**P.S.** I just need a UID, unique number assigned to each value same as autoincrement.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to provide sample data and desired results.  In my experience, `row_number()` works fine in BigQuery in both base tables and views.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it works fine, I'm not complaining about that this is not working. Sorry if I explained it incorrectly.... The main issue that AFTER day of running the query and save data to separate table. The table AND a view start to have different UID value. BUT initially I have made this table out of this view

Comment: Ordering is only guaranteed for the columns you specify in the ORDER BY clause.  So for `OVER (ORDER BY date)` could return `(2018-01-01,1)` as the first row and sometime later it could be `(2018-01-01,2)`. I guess that is what you're noticing.

Comment: @SalmanA Yes, after a day this numbers a changed, so I need something stable and which will not change, any other UID techniques??

Comment: Just include primary key to the ORDER BY (assuming that it increments each time a row is inserted).

Comment: Or just concatenate a couple columns which will give you a unique number - e.g. a customer number and a timestamp for that row if it'll always be unique

Comment: @Bobbylank, unfortunately, this simple solution is not applicable. As I have dupes even after concat columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just need a UID, unique number assigned to each value ...

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

You can try using [FARM_FINGERPRINT()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/hash_functions#farm_fingerprint) function - either by itself or if you have whole rows as a duplicates as a part of `OVER(ORDER BY ...)`

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  FARM_FINGERPRINT(TO_JSON_STRING(t)) uid,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY FARM_FINGERPRINT(TO_JSON_STRING(t))) row_num
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

Comment: Thank you, that is sound as a cool idea. I will check it and will let you know.